# How to scrape specific text from a webpage in Python?

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I want to quickly obtain the day's bet rate from [winmasters.com](http://www.winmasters.com).

This is what i have until now:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://winmasters.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
team = tree.xpath('//div["class="display-table"]/text()')
odds = tree.xpath('//span[@class="ng-binding ng-scope"]/text()')

print 'Team: ', team
print 'odds: ',  odds
```

thx

Comment: So what's the problem? What output are you getting, and how is it different from your expected output? Are you getting any errors? Please [edit] your question and add all these details. As it stands, your question is unclear.

Comment: Additionally, the site is disabled in certain countries (including the US), so it's going to be pretty difficult to help...

Comment: The code dont return me any values

Answer (score 0):

That url just takes you to the frontpage, which doesn't give any values.

You need to figure out which page to go to, ie `http://www.winmasters.com/en/sports/#/category/2/`